# What is this magic trick with a sarcophagus shaped box and a set of tokens?

Tags: puzzle-identification, magic

I have a set of kids' magic tricks but I have lost the instructions! I was hoping this might be a good place to get some help.

Here is the second one.[image]

This one might be a little more tricky but what is this magic trick and how does it work?

What you can't see is that the rectangular box is hollow.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything on the reverse of those little black circles?

Comment: @randal'thor No, if you mean the one black circle with no picture on it. There is one black circle which you can see with nothing on the other side. The own two which are on the yellow shape are attached to it.

Comment: The thing with a hand and a rope is the box in which it was stored?

Comment: @leoll2 Yes. That is the box all the 10 tricks came in.

Comment: Do the black coins fit inside the holes in the boat shape? Are the small red and blue things magnets? If so how do they interact with the coins?

Comment: @IanF1 the black coins fit in the holes. The small read and blue things are not magnets. One fits all the way through the hole in the second picture and the other gets stuck some way through it.

Comment: This question is asking for identification. It's not a puzzle.

Comment: @Ric Yes.  There were extensive meta discussion at one point about what was on-topic for puzzle.se.  There were those who wanted questions about puzzles and those who wanted the questions to be puzzles if I recall correctly. I have no idea what the conclusion was, if any.

Comment: @Ric There's a special [tag](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-identification) for puzzle-identification questions, so this question definitely seems to be on-topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My younger brother likes magic and so I recognize the boat.

The boat + the tokens is already a set, everything else is from another trick.

The trick is that you magically place the same sequence of images as a volunteer. There are two tokens of each image and there is a trick token which is black on both sides and looks like the bottom of the holes. I split the tokens between us so that we both have the same images, and I have the special token. I say that I'll place my tokens face down, the volunteer will place his face up, and we'll both place the same sequence of images even though I started.

How it's done: I first place the special token, then I mimic his images (as I can see them), and finally when he place his second to last token, I place two tokens as one: the same image and then my last token (because I know that is also his last token, and thus what he will place next). Then I reveal my face down tokens.

Comment: you place the tokens on the table? In the boat?

Comment: @KateGregory, In the boat so that the trick token will look like the bottom of the hole when you take out the other tokens.

Comment: The tokens look about the same diameter as the hole.  How do you remove them during the reveal while leaving the double sided black on in the boat? Is there enough room to fish them out with fingers? Does the boat top get used during the trick?

Comment: @AdamDavis, You're right, they're about the same diameter as the hole. You can't fish them out with your fingers, you have to tilt it over a bit. The boat top doesn't get used during the trick (and now I see that the boat top is painted as a sarcophagus, so the boat is actually meant to be a sarcophagus).

Comment: I have a few more tricks I can't work out. Your knowledge of the brother's magic tricks may turn out very useful!

Answer (score 9):

["Egyption Prediction" YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSnHz3K_230)

[image: screencap from YouTube video]
["Egyptian Prediction" & other magic tricks (How-To) PDF](http://mediacdn.shopatron.com/media/mfg/677/media_document/dev_1/1170InstructionsNEW1-15-13.pdf?1389910672)

[image: original toy set, 2004]

Comment: you are most welcome☥Happy Magic!ʕʘ‿ʘʔ◞*:･ﾟ✧